# Custom libc++ for Android

Tags: android, c++, stl, clang, libc++

Let's say that I'm going to ship AAR, which includes C++(jni) library.
Android docs [suggest](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#shared_runtimes) to ship single native library which links libc++ statically and hides all symbols except Java_xxx.
As one of the most important arguments is the fact that if you link libc++_shared.so you have to ship that library with your aar and it might conflict with other aar's libc++_shares.so or with app's own one. Well, its pretty clear.

Nevertheless I still want to ship my library with shared version of libc++.

Can't be there another option? As described [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-release-r19/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md#libc) it's the llvm's [libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/) and it's possible to build it with [option](https://releases.llvm.org/10.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/BuildingLibcxx.html#cmdoption-arg-libcxx-abi-namespace-string) to specify abi namespace which should help to compile custom libc++ with unique symbols:

> LIBCXX_ABI_NAMESPACE:STRING¶
> Default: __n where n is the current ABI version.
>
> This option defines the name of the inline ABI versioning namespace. It can be used for building custom versions of libc++ with unique symbol names in order to prevent conflicts or ODR issues with other libc++ versions.

So the plan is to build custom libc++ with unique LIBCXX_ABI_NAMESPACE (for example __iddqd), name library with unique prefix (my_libc++.so), build my library with this my_libc++.so instead of Android's libc++ and that's it. No conflicts with third parties aars and apps, but still shared version of libc++.

Does it make sense? Did I miss something important? Anybody has an experience with such approach?

Comment: but what's android's libc++ ?

Comment: this thing has other name

Comment: Android doesn't provide libc++ (unlike for example ios). When you build a native library with libc++ you must ship libc++_shared.so. Gradle usually picks up it from NDK, they are different from NDK version to version. The problem is that if anybody else also ships libc++_shared.so in different aar in the same app they might be of different versions, but only one ends up in the final app and only one is loaded be library loader. So it might break either my aar or their aar with hardly understandable crashes.

Comment: " instead of Android's libc++".  there's llvm one but not android's.

Comment: NDK provides llvm's libc++ (which is shipped with the aar/app if necessary), according to documentation, see the link I provided. Android operation system doesn't contain any system-wide.

Comment: yeah. i've seen like `libc++` alternative that's free of licence